# How to modify join to get the identical prices to match up

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a comparison query that is working pretty well but I have a number of results where the prices that I think should match up appearing in different rows.  Is there any good way to get them to match up for a given ticker & account to they would be excluded from my result set?

Query:

```
with cteDev3 (Sequence, AccountID, SecurityID, Ticker, UniqueAccountID, BuyPrice, BuyDate, Shares)as
      (select Al.Sequence, Al.AccountID, al.SecurityID, s.Ticker,ad.UniqueAccountId, BuyPrice, BuyDate, Shares
        from dev3TM2.dbo.AccountLot al
        join dev3TM2.dbo.AccountDetails ad
        on al.AccountID = ad.AccountId
        join dev3TM2.dbo.Security s
        on al.SecurityId = s.SecurityId
        where ad.EnterpriseId = 'HuberFinancial'),
    cteTest2 (Sequence, AccountID, SecurityID,Ticker, UniqueAccountID, BuyPrice, BuyDate, Shares)as
       (select Al.Sequence, Al.AccountID, al.SecurityID, s.Ticker,ad.UniqueAccountId, BuyPrice, BuyDate, Shares
        from test2TM2.dbo.AccountLot al
        join test2TM2.dbo.AccountDetails ad
        on al.AccountID = ad.AccountId
        join Test2TM2.dbo.Security s
        on al.SecurityId = s.SecurityId
        where ad.EnterpriseId = 'HuberFinancial')

select c3.UniqueAccountId as 'Dev3', t2.UniqueAccountId as 'Test2',c3.Ticker, t2.Ticker,
       c3.Shares,t2.Shares, c3.BuyDate, t2.BuyDate, c3.BuyPrice as 'Dev3_BuyPrice', t2.BuyPrice as 'Test2_BuyPrice'
from cteTest2 t2 full outer join
     cteDev3 c3
     on c3.UniqueAccountId = t2.UniqueAccountId
where
--c3.UniqueAccountID is null or t2.UniqueAccountID is null and
        c3.SecurityID = t2.SecurityID and
        c3.BuyDate = t2.BuyDate and
       c3.Shares = t2.Shares and
        (c3.BuyPrice <= t2.BuyPrice -0.001 or c3.BuyPrice >=t2.BuyPrice + 0.001) 
        --c3.BuyPrice = t2.BuyPrice
order by c3.UniqueAccountID, t2.UniqueAccountID, c3.Ticker, t2.Ticker, c3.BuyDate, t2.BuyDate,
c3.BuyPrice, t2.BuyPrice
```

Result Set (partial):

```
Dev3 | Test2 | Ticker | Ticker | Shares | Shares | BuyDate | BuyDate | Dev3_BuyPrice | Test2_BuyPrice
10735975 | 10735975 | TLM | TLM | 100.000000 | 100.000000 | 2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 11.859000 | 11.860000
10735975 | 10735975 | TLM | TLM | 100.000000 | 100.000000 | 2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 11.860000 | 11.859000
11123259 | 11123259 | EDC | EDC | 0.297700 | 0.297700 | 2010-03-31 00:00:00 | 2010-03-31 00:00:00 | 163.329750 | 163.318777
11123259 | 11123259 | EDC | EDC | 0.337700 | 0.337700 | 2010-06-30 00:00:00 | 2010-06-30 00:00:00 | 110.489221 | 110.482677
11123259 | 11123259 | EDC | EDC | 1.379500 | 1.379500 | 2011-03-30 00:00:00 | 2011-03-30 00:00:00 | 201.048191 | 201.051105
11123259 | 11123259 | EDC | EDC | 0.023500 | 0.023500 | 2011-03-30 00:00:00 | 2011-03-30 00:00:00 | 201.105442 | 201.276596
11123259 | 11123259 | EDC | EDC | 1.022900 | 1.022900 | 2011-06-29 00:00:00 | 2011-06-29 00:00:00 | 179.398940 | 179.391925
11123259 | 11123259 | EDC | EDC | 0.063500 | 0.063500 | 2011-06-29 00:00:00 | 2011-06-29 00:00:00 | 179.414542 | 179.527559
```

Comment: Are you trying to say `Abs( c3.BuyPrice - t2.BuyPrice ) <= 0.001`?

Comment: No I am not.   Thanks for reminding me of the ABS function though.  This is actually Abs( c3.BuyPrice - t2.BuyPrice ) >= 0.001  I want prices that are outside of that range.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but you are looking at differences in prices less than a tenth of a cent (okay, I'm assuming dollars).

The examples you give seem to differ by that amount.

Perhaps you should try:

```
abs(c3.BuyPrice - t2.BuyPrice) >= 0.01
```

this will eliminate most of the examples you have.

Comment: Some of the data may have been a bit of a red herring.  I am particularly interested if trying to figure out if there is a way that I can get the first two rows lined up so they can be excluded.  Right now off of a compare of over 200K + records I get about 1000 back with a number of them having mismatches like the one in the first two records.

Comment: The first two records are probably due to a rounding error.  Just change the value from 0.001 to something larger . . . 0.002?  0.005?  0.01?  Any of these will probably do.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of your price and quantity fields away from floating-point. You don't want this type of rounding error, nor do the various accountants and certification agencies. Either the built in [Money](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) type, or an integral type with your own scale to place the decimal point, preferably the former.